# How to set X axis min and max

Tags: android, time-series, achartengine

I'm trying to set X axis min and max. I found methods `mRenderer.setXAxisMax(value);
            mRenderer.setXAxisMin(value);` but i don't know how set X in TimeSeries.

When I use timestamp `mRenderer.setXAxisMin(1347963701812)` it says that int is out of range

When I use string `mRenderer.setXAxisMin("2012-09-20 15:00:00")` it says that is not applicable for String.

How set min and max X date on TimeSeries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question, it worth being mentioned that when you say "it", the "it" is the Java compiler.

Just make the compiler understand that you are passing a double value that doesn't fit into an int:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(1347963701812.0);
```